# Angularjs xeditable selected option not shown

Tags: angularjs, html-select, x-editable

I have editable rows in a table and I can't seem to **show the selected value in my dropdown list**. Everything else in the process works fine.

Code at: http://jsfiddle.net/bzLj3a5q/7/

Html:

```
...
<span editable-select="ad.ad_type_id" e-name="ad_type_id" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="id as type for (id,type) in ad_types" onshow="showType(ad)">
                    {{ ad_types[ad.ad_type_id] }}
                </span>
...
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['xeditable']);

app.run(function (editableOptions) {editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; });

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {

$scope.ads = [
    {
        "id": "abc",        
        "ad_type_id": 1        
    },
    {
        "id": "def",        
        "ad_type_id": 2

    }
];


$scope.ad_types = {
    "1": "Type1",
    "2": "Type2",
    "3": "Type3"
};

$scope.showType = function(ad) {
    $scope.ad_type_id = ad.ad_type_id;
    $scope.apply;
};
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was breaking when comparing the **string** value of the keys in `ad_types` with the **integer** values in `ads`. The solution is to force the keys of `ad_types` to integer like this:

```
<span editable-select="ad.ad_type_id" e-name="ad_type_id" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="toInt(id) as type for (id,type) in ad_types">{{ ad_types[ad.ad_type_id] }}</span>
```

and define the `toInt(id)` method in the controller:

```
// We need this to force the key of the ad_types object to an integer
// (as the API returns integer values for ad_type_id)
$scope.toInt = function(key) {
    // 10 is the radix, which is the base
    return parseInt(key, 10); 
}
```

The updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/bzLj3a5q/13/

Answer (score 1):

Switching your object to the following fixes the issue...

```
$scope.ad_types = {
    1: "Type1",
    2: "Type2",
    3: "Type3"
};
```

and multiplying by 1 is an easy fix too..

e-ng-options="(id * 1) as type for (id,type) in productSizes"